# Substitute argument of `fix` in proof

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

This question is probably trivial, but I'm stuck on it since yesterday and I couldn't find the relevant keyword to search for.

Consider the following:

```
Fixpoint mfp (t: nat*nat) := fst t.

Lemma ml: forall (t: nat*nat), mfp t = fst t.
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold mfp.
  (* substitute t0 with t in lhs *)
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

After unfolding `mfp`, I have to prove `(fix mfp (t0 : nat * nat) : nat := fst t0) t = fst t` which trivially holds, yet I don't know how to tell Coq "Do the substitution of `t0` by `t`".

Do you know how to do that substitution ?

Comment: `destruct t` would trigger computation in this case. Is this a minimized example? Because `Definition mfp (t: nat*nat) := fst t.` would let you get rid of that `destruct`.

Comment: `destruct` works in my case thanks :-) . Yes, I wrote a `Fixpoint` instead of `Definition` because this is minimized.