# Coq:prove Prop implies arithmetic relations of natural number

Tags: math, coq, proof, prop

I'm trying to prove the following Lemma in coq --

```
Lemma less_than_two_equivalent: forall x, less_than_two x = true -> x < 2.
```

based on the definition below.

```
Fixpoint less_than (a b:nat): bool:=
match a, b with
|0, 0 => false
|0, _ => true
|S a', 0 => false
|S a', S b' => less_than a' b'
end.

Fixpoint less_than_two (x:nat) : bool  := if less_than x 2 then true else false.
```

Mathematically, there are only 2 cases, 0 or 1. And `destruction`should be the hammer, but there won't be enough information about the S x for further reasoning.

Should I modify the less_than into inductive datatypes? If not, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me begin by redefining `less_than_two`. First, it's not recursive, so there is no point in defining it as a `Fixpoint`. Next, `if less_than x 2 then true else false` is essentially the same thing as `less_than x 2`. And at this point I wouldn't bother with introducing a new definition, so your lemma becomes

```
Lemma less_than_two_equivalent x: less_than x 2 = true -> x < 2. 
Proof.
  do 2 (destruct x; auto); simpl.
  destruct x; discriminate.
Qed.
```

I don't know what went wrong with your proof exactly, but you might have forgotten to destruct `x` one more time. When you see `less_than x 0 = true -> S (S x) < 2` you can't still use `discriminate` to finish your goal, because evaluation is blocked on the variable -- `less_than` first pattern-matches on the `a` parameter and only then checks `b`. Destruction of `x` unblocks computation and lets Coq see that you have `false = true` as your premise, hence the goal becomes provable.

Note that this depends on the particular implementation of the comparison function. Had you chose this one

```
(* (!) the [struct] annotation is important here, as well as as
   the order of the parameters [b, a] in the match expression *)

Fixpoint less_than' (a b : nat) {struct b} : bool :=
  match b, a with
  | 0, _ => false
  | _, 0 => true
  | S b', S a' => less_than' a' b'
  end.
```

you would have a bit simpler proof (one less `destruct`):

```
Lemma less_than_two_equivalent x: less_than' x 2 = true -> x < 2. 
Proof.
  do 2 (destruct x; auto).
  discriminate.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the insights. The reason I define it that way is to use it as a smaller machinery to pass it to a fold function define below.

Comment: `Fixpoint fold {X Y:Type} (f: X->Y->Y) (l:list X) (b:Y)  : Y :=
  match l with
  | nil => b
  | h :: t => f h (fold f t b)
  end.` Due to the way list is constructed, the definition needs to be of type (`f: X->Y->Y`). Logically they are equivalent. And it's reasonable to question about my definition, it's just that I didn't give enough context for it.

Comment: `Fixpoint` and `Definition` are *not* equivalent. This piece of code should demonstrate the difference I mean: `Fixpoint less_than_two (x:nat) : bool  := less_than x 2.
Definition less_than_two' (x:nat) : bool  := less_than x 2.

Goal forall x, less_than x 2 = less_than_two x.
  Fail reflexivity.
  intros x; destruct x; reflexivity.
Qed.

Goal forall x, less_than x 2 = less_than_two' x.
  reflexivity.
Qed.`

Comment: This is a related to my last comment issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52382140/2747511